# Mat in C++ to Numpy

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I have three C++ matrices called `myMatrix`, `myMatrix2` and `canvas` respectively using OpenCV. I'm pretty new to C++, so it's unclear to me what Range::all() does. I understand the second Range statement, and I'm wondering if `Range::all()` is equivalent to `Range(0,myMatrix.rows)`?

```
    myMatrix.copyTo(canvas(Range::all(), Range(0, myMatrix2.cols)));
```

I'm thinking it should be something like:

```
canvas = np.copy(myMatrix[:][:myMatrix2.cols])
```

Comment: How do you have *two matrices in C++* but I only see python syntax? :S What are you exactly trying to do? and in which language, python or c++? Do you mean just translating equivalent C++ syntax to python?

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I'm trying to convert the C++ syntax to Python. And apologies, there are 3 matrices in both.

Comment: Ops I was just editing the question, I'll try to answer it.

Comment: there are no build in matrices in c++ what library are you using?

Comment: @AnderBiguri obviously...I'm converting the first line to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I did understand properly, the numpy equivalent can be written as:

```
canvas = np.copy(myMatrix[:, :myMatrix2.shape[1]])
```

Assuming that both `myMatrix` and `myMatrix2` exist. If `canvas` also exists in python beforehand, you can update it inplace (rather than creating a new copy) as:

```
canvas[:] = myMatrix[:, :myMatrix2.shape[1]]
```

The `:` is the equivalent to `Range::all()` while `:myMatrix2.shape[1]` is equivalent to `Range(0, myMatrix2.cols)`.

You should first learn how to use numpy (it has a [great manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html)) rather than trying to make something work blindly.

Comment: thanks, I will read the documentation. Was in a rush to get this finished. Thank you.